# Extract adjacent paths from a SVG file

Tags: svg

I have an ungrouped SVG file which has 3 different images and having its own path values in a XML file. I want to decompose this single SVG file into 3 different SVG files (one for each image). So basically I should be able to find all the paths of image#1 and write to a new file and so on to other files. Problem is, how can I find the paths of single image. I understand that I should extract all the paths which are adjacent to each other...

Note: All the three images in a master SVG file are not touching each other. So paths of one image will not overlap with another.

If the master SVG file is a grouped SVG file. I can easily extract the paths between `<g>` and `</g>` tags. So my job will be easy. But the files that I have are ungrouped, hence I am not able to identify the adjacent paths.

Comment: in my research sofar, I couldn't find any way of finding adjacent paths using inkscape... inkscape can edit or manipulate a given path, but not sure if it can find adjacent paths?? is it still possible with inkscape?

Comment: How many paths do you have? is this something you can't do by eye?

Comment: I am planning to write a script as I have more than 100 files to process... each master svg file may have more than 50 paths.... if it is for only one file, I can easily do by eye by trial n error... but my intention is to automate....

Comment: If you'd fit each image into its own rectangle, would they overlap? Is their position always the same in all files?

Comment: @suj Ah, that makes sense, I had understood that you had one file.